# Routing between two subnets on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, routing, rras

I have a Windows Server 2008 box. One interface is on a VPN (5.140.164.156/8) and one is on the local netowrk (192.168.1.253/24) I have enabled RRAS and on a different machine on my LAN I have added a static route route to the VPN via 192.168.1.253. A traceroute only gets as far as 192.168.1.253. Is there another step that I need to take?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: The server at 192.168.1.253 has to be able to route the traffic from one NIC to the other NIC, which I don't believe it's going to do by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installing RRAS [used to silently enable IP forwarding on the machine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262083), but this might not be the case anymore. Check your RAS config to see if forwarding is enabled. Also, with RRAS you are able to specify packet filtering rules - check that the current ruleset is not blocking your transfers.